# Create new user with new tenant in ABP Framework

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, abp

I customized a new registration page in Blazor Wasm and want to create a new User with new Tenant. I wanted to use ITenantAppService.CreateAsync but it occurred permission problem.

```
var tenantDto = await _tenantAppService.CreateAsync(new TenantCreateDto()
            {
                Name = dto.UserName,
                AdminEmailAddress = dto.EmailAddress,
                AdminPassword = dto.Password,
            });
```

[image]

Isn't it possible to create a Tenant by anonymous user?
I think I need to remove this permissions from tenantService or I need to give these permissions to anonymous user.

How can I create new tenant for new user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution.
Firstly, I tried to remove permissions but I didn't know how to remove easily. Then I tried firstly creating a user without tenant, then give him tenant.create permission but it didn't work.
Finally, I created a class

```
CustomTenantAppService : TenantManagementAppServiceBase, ITenantAppService
```

and implemented methods of ITenantAppService, so I could do everything that I want.

Comment: Hi,
I'm happy to find the solution. Also, you may mark your answer as a correct answer.  FYI